# Can a MailItem change after being decrypted because of exchange sync issues?

Tags: vb.net, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I have code in a VSTO addin to decrypt emails in an Outlook 16 client.  The email account is with MS Excahnge.  Full code is below but I hope there are no surprises with this code. I am not creating a copy of the email. I have noticed that sometimes when I decrypt an email it automatically encrypts again. On other times the body of the email disappears in my decrypted email.

I believe this is because of sync issues with exchange but am not sure, nor do I understand exactly what the sync issue is. I think a copy of many of these emails end up in a Sync Issues folder.

Is the email not fully downloaded from the server? Or Is Outlook "re-syncing" old emails again, wrongly seeing a difference in the emails (because the client has a changed email through the decryption) and therefore downloading the email again?

My question is how can I fix this? What do I need to wait for or how can I ensure that my changes to the email locally will be synced to the server correctly?

Below is my code. I basically leverage the MailItem.PropertyAccessor and the PR_SECURITY_FLAGS to set the value to 0. I therefore call the below funtion SetExtendedPropertyDecryptValue passing in a MmailItem object and the PR_SECURITY_FLAGS value. The property is then set to SECFLAG_NONE.

```
Const PR_SECURITY_FLAGS As String = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x6E010003"
Const SECFLAG_NONE = &H0
Const SECFLAG_ENCRYPTED = &H1
Const SECFLAG_SIGNED = &H2
Const SECFLAG_ENCRYPTED_SIGNED = &H3
Const SECFLAG_BITWISE = &H3


Private Function SetExtendedPropertyDecryptValue(ByVal aMailItem As Outlook.MailItem, ByVal aProperty As String) As Boolean
    Dim uFlag As Long
    GetExtendedPropertyValue(aMailItem, aProperty, uFlag)
    If (uFlag And SECFLAG_BITWISE) = SECFLAG_NONE Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return SetExtendedPropertyValue(aMailItem, PR_SECURITY_FLAGS, uFlag And SECFLAG_NONE)
    End If

End Function



Private Function GetExtendedPropertyValue(ByVal aMailItem As Outlook.MailItem, ByVal aProperty As String, ByRef res As Object) As Boolean

    Dim oPropAcc As Outlook.PropertyAccessor = Nothing

    Try
        oPropAcc = DirectCast(aMailItem.PropertyAccessor, Outlook.PropertyAccessor)
        res = oPropAcc.GetProperty(aProperty)

        Return True

    Catch ex As System.Exception
        'logging goes here
    Finally
        If Not oPropAcc Is Nothing Then
            Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oPropAcc)
            oPropAcc = Nothing
        End If
    End Try
    Return False
End Function



Private Function SetExtendedPropertyValue(ByVal aMailItem As Outlook.MailItem, ByVal aProperty As String, ByVal value As Integer) As Boolean
    Dim oPropAcc As Outlook.PropertyAccessor = Nothing
    Try
        oPropAcc = DirectCast(aMailItem.PropertyAccessor, Outlook.PropertyAccessor)
        oPropAcc.SetProperty(aProperty, value)

        Return True
    Catch ex As System.Exception
        'logging goes here
    Finally
        If Not oPropAcc Is Nothing Then
            Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oPropAcc)
            oPropAcc = Nothing
        End If
    End Try
    Return False
End Function
```

Comment: Try to call the `Save` method after making any modifications to the mail object. Do you still see sync issues after that?

Comment: Yes save is being called.

Comment: I don't see any Save calls in your code posted.

Comment: Sorry, for not posting that actual piece of code, however, yes it is saved.

Answer (score 0):

Try to preserve existing security flags when you add or remove any other flags. So, if you want to get it decrypted there is no need to remove the SECFLAG_SIGNED flag.

Comment: Sorry if "decrypt" is misleading. I want to strip both signed and encrypted flags. As you posted this an an answer, I just want to check, do you think this is the problem?

Comment: Do you get the same problems when you decrypt emails manually in Outlook? are they still signed? have you tried checking the PR_SECURITY_FLAGS  value after the operation is made manually?

Comment: At this stage I have no idea what is causing my problem and cannot reliably reproduce the issues. So I am not sure making changes for a problem I don't see is going to help.

Comment: I'd suggest narrowing down the problem by extracting the problematic lines of code. May be another pieces of your add-in have any impact to this problem.